# Finding the number of matching letters in two different string at the same indices

Tags: python

I am having trouble finish python code.

overlap('','hello') → 0.

I have managed to get the number back when the length of the strings match but if one of the strings has a smaller length than the other. I keep getting index out of range. Can someone help me finish this.

```
def overlap(string1,string2):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(string1)):
        for j in range(len(string2)):
            if string1[i] == string2[j]:
                count = count + 1
                i+=1
            else:
                i+=1
        return count
```

When running this with a function call. if both strings are equal it gives me the correct number, but if one is smaller or longer then its index out of range. 
Thanks

Comment: For what input are you getting that error?

Comment: It happens when the smaller string is string 1 and the larger one is string 2, For example: string 1: summer, string2: sum, works fine, but string1:sum and string2: summer gives index error, my teacher uses a tester file so we can't change inputs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create **one** `for` loop  which iterates through `min(len(string1), len(string2))` and you would avoid problem when one string is smaller than another, see sample below:

```
def overlap(string1,string2):
    count = 0
    for i in range(min(len(string1), len(string2))):
        if string1[i] == string2[i]:
            count = count + 1
    return count

print overlap('summer','winter') #2
print overlap('abcb','dbeb') #2
print overlap('summer','sum') #3
print overlap('','winter') #0
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Replace the nested loops and repeat only for the smaller length.

```
def overlap(string1, string2):
    count=0;
    len1= len(string1)
    len2= len(string2)
    smallLen= len1
    if len2<len1:
        smallLen= len2

    for i in range(smallLen):
        if string1[i]== string2[i]:
            count+= 1
    return count
```

Comment: Welcome. Glad could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about it in order of things that need to be done, you have to first figure out which of the two given strings have the shortest length because that will be your bound for the amount of loop iterations. In Python you can do a conditional assignment like:

```
maxloop = len(str1) if len(str1) <= len(str2) else len(str2)
```

You make the condition `<=` because it doesnt matter which is chosen if they're equal, so just pick the first.

Now that you have the amount of iterations you'll do, you can set up the loop and counter:

```
count = 0
for i in range(maxloop):
    if str1[i] == str2[i]:
        count += 1
```

The single `if` statement is checking the character at position `i` in both strings and seeing if they are equal, and if they are, then it'll add one to the overlap counter. Then simply return the count after the loop has terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
count = 0
if len(string1) < len(string2):
    for i in range(len(string1)):
        if string1[i] == string2[i]:
            count += 1
else:
    for i in range(len(string2)):
        if string1[i] == string2[i]:
            count += 1
return count
```